# Maximum number of coins from a tech?

Tags: civilization-board-game

On page 26 of the [rulebook](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/1a/10/1a1063a1-ee84-44ac-a79a-237277010a6f/civ_rulebook_eng_lo-res.pdf) it says

> Coin tokens placed on a tech card as a reward for accomplishing a
>   certain task are treated just like coins on the map, **except that there
>   is a maximum number of times a given task will provide a coin token**.
>   Coin tokens advance the economy dial when gained and cannot be lost

Since there are ways to remove a coin token from a tech, how is the maximum number on the tech card interpreted?

a) The maximum number on the card means the **maximum number of times that you may use this ability.**

b) The maximum number on the card means the **maximum number of coins that can be placed on the card using this ability.**

## Example

The pottery tech card reads `max 4`. Player A uses this four times (on four different rounds) and gets four coin tokens on it. Player B plays a culture card which enables him to discard a coin token on a technology card, and discards one of the coin tokens from the player A's Pottery card.

Can player A use the ability on the Pottery card *fifth* time to get a *fourth* coin token on the tech card?

[image: Pottery Card]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Official FAQ v2](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/civilization/news/Civilization%20FAQ_v2.0.pdf):

> Q: What exactly does “(max 4)” mean on techs such as Democracy, Code
> of Laws, or Pottery?
>
> A: It means that a player can only have four coin
> tokens on the Tech card at one time. If a coin token is removed from
> the card, the player can fulfill the condition on the card to add
> another coin token to it.